# EMGU CV, C#, Visual Studio 2013, sudden "Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242' on new Capture"

Tags: c#, opencv

I have a small project I just started. It was working fine. But suddenly I get the following error on the line _capture = new Capture.

{"Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}

I've read numerous issues similar to this, mostly people installing EMGU CV and trying to get a project going. I have other projects that still work, using the same code, but my current one and new ones I make have this issue.

For some the solution is to add .dll files, like nvcuda.dll or tbb*.dll to the working directory or the Windows32 directory, because opencv_core242.dl can't find them. This doesn't make sense for me though because my other projects are working without any wild additions, and this project was working until it stopped, and now new projects get this error. I find a lot of people with this error when first setting up, but no one inexplicable having it appear in a proven setup.

I've re-referenced the needed libraries in Visual Studio (Emgu.CV, Emgu.CV.UI, Emgu.Util), and I've even gone though the Visual Studio repair process.

What should I be looking at here? I'm getting more confused.

Thanks.

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace LaneFollowing_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Capture _capture = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _capture = new Capture();
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += processImage;
            _capture.Start();
        }

        void processImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Capture image. 
            Image<Bgr, Byte> img = _capture.RetrieveBgrFrame().Resize(400, 300, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
            imageBox1.Image = img;
            //CvInvoke.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a sample project to the Emgu.Example folder. This project had dlls in its lib folder. Could this be confusing thing?

Comment: I think I see the problem. It should be looking for opencv_core2410, not opencv_core242. The example project I put in Emgu.Example must have screwed something up. I've deleted the sample project now, and removed the references. Shut down Visual Studio. It's still trying to find opencv_core242. Now what should I do? Does VS make it harder or easier to develop stuff? lol